# Image slider in android using library

Tags: android, slider

I am using the library [AndroidTouchGallery](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery)

but I want the image width and screen width to match.
I can manage the height by giving specific size but the width is displayed less than screen size.

please help me in this...

Comment: Well posting an answer to my own question.

For those like me who had to use a library but did not want to use it. Well u can always try with a horizontal list and setting image as list item, But then It might not be that easy to show just one image at a time.But it will scroll horizontally

Comment: u can also use the [link]"http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html" grid list